# How can I get this kind of output using MS sql

Tags: sql, linq

I've two tables

```
  Employee
```

Id    Name      salary   DeptId
1     john       100       1
2     Nicolas    200       1
3     Chris      300       2
4     jonny      400       3
5     leo        500       5
6     jim        600       4
7     bryan      700       4

---

### Dept

DeptID    DeptName

1         HR
2         MGR
3         Support
4         Admin
5         Staff

---

I've tried query as:

select d.deptname,CONCAT(e.name,'') from emp e inner join dept d on e.deptid=d.deptid group by d.deptname,e.name

---

Output: How Can I get this Output ?

DeptName  EmpNames(list of Names)

HR       john,Nicolas
MGR      Chris
Support  jonny
Admin    jim,bryan
Staff    leo

Comment: Have you tried anything, or do you expect us to do all the work? If so, what have you tried? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: this can done using some effort on your part

Comment: Linq? SQL? What do you expect? Which ORM are you using?